# How to assign all members at once in Trello's card?

Tags: trello

I run an agency. We have about 60 artists + other members. When there is an audition, I want to create a card and add all members with one action, not one by one, as I do now. Is this possible? And if yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Trello recently implemented [Card Copying](http://blog.trello.com/card-copying-and-mini-profiles/) functionality, allowing you to copy members, checklists, labels, attachments, and comments from one card to another.  If you're only looking to keep the same members from one card to another, simply uncheck all of the options other than "Members".  This would allow you to copy all 60 members from the old card while avoiding copying any of the data from the previous card.
[image: copyCard]